# how to uninstall WPS office software which is installed on user space like from patch managment tool like DCM?

Tags: window, uninstallation

i am using this command "%LocalAppData%\Kingsoft\WPS Office\11.2.0.11516\utility\uninst.exe" /s to uninstall wps software from remote tool but %localappdat% always select local admin profile  but this setup (uninst.exe) installed on user profile.

is there any way that i can run script as target user which always select mention user profile and it take local admin user name like .\localadmin and password to uninstall run the above .exe file

i have tried to run this command from backend tool like DCM/SCCM  as target user but its popup user id and password to end user for uninstallation

is there any way i can put local admin user/password like ".\adminuser" and password